# thread waits until task is done

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't know how to make for a thread to run until the task is finished.
So i have this class:

```
public class MainTest {

public static void main(String[] args){

    ThreadRunnable t1 = new ThreadRunnable();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);
    t2.start();
    System.out.println(3);
    //here the next code to run

}
}
```

And another that try for example to add data in database:

```
public class ThreadRunnable implements Runnable{

public void run(){
    //code to make the thread waits until the insert is done
    //code for inserting data in database
}

}
```

So, inside method run() i want something like: 
 - try to insert data in database
 - if connection to database is down, wait 5 seconds and try again
 - if connection is ok, then insert data, and return successful message that data is added

Is this possible, and if yes, how?
Thanks!

Comment: A good way to implement your idea about "wait 5 seconds and try again" is to use a `Timer` that runs a `TimerTaks`. Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to wait for a thread.  Just do the retries in a loop in your Runnable:

```
public void run() {
    try {

        while (true) {
            try {
                // Do database operations here

                // Succeeded
                break;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // Failed;  log exception and try again.
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Couldn't save data.", e);
            }

            // Wait before trying again.
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Interrupted; exiting.", e);
    }
}
```

Note:  An interrupt is an explicit request for a thread to *stop what it’s doing* and self-terminate.  The InterruptedException should not be caught inside the loop, because you *want* the loop to terminate in the event of an interrupt.

On the other hand, you do want the loop to keep executing in the event of an SQLException, so it should be caught inside the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't be `InterruptedException` rethrown or `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` called to retain interrupted flag?

Comment: @rkosegi Ideally, it should not be rethrown, but rather should be added to the enclosing method’s `throws` clause, so it never needs to be caught in the first place. But that’s not an option in a Runnable, which only has a `public void run()` method.  Setting the interrupt again won’t make a difference in a Thread, and it might actually interfere with the operation of an ExecutorService, if one were in use.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that :

1) Add a waitFor function in your ThreadRunnable
2) Add synchronization via un LOCK variable

The code :

```
    public class ThreadRunnable implements Runnable{

    private boolean ended=false;

     private final Object LOCK=new Object();

    public void run(){

          // do my stuff...
          ...

          //at the end, notify the thread waiting for : it will wake up
          synchronized(LOCK)
          {
               ended=true;
               LOCK.notifyAll();
          }

    }

    /**
     Waits until the task is done
    */
    public void waitFor()
    {
        synchronized(LOCK)
        {
             while(!ended)
             {
                  //sleeps until notifAll is called (see run())
                  wait();
             }
        }
    }

    }
```

(in this code, you have to add the try/catch for the InterruptedException)
In your main :

```
public class MainTest {

public static void main(String[] args){

    ThreadRunnable t1 = new ThreadRunnable();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);
    t2.start();
    t1.waitFor();
    System.out.println(3);
    //here the next code to run

}
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about `CountdownLatch`?

Comment: Until now, never :) I've looked the Java doc, it seems pretty. You could post an answer with a sample ? Thanks for the information